# REACT Native Modal transparent prop is bugging on Android

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, expo

The transparent prop on Modals leads to an error on Android simulator but not on iOS.

`<Modal visible={props.visible} transparent='true' animationType='slide' >`

The error says:
Error while updating property 'transparent' of a view managed by: RCTModalHostView

If I simply remove the transparent prop then it works but I loose my transparent background obviously which I can't have happening.

I run expo 3.4.1

Comment: Can you post expo snack?

Answer (score 2):

The type of transporter is `Bool`. But you're putting the type in a string. `iOS` may recognize your string as a `Bool`, but `Android` may not. Fill out the type according to the type.

### transparent

The transparent prop determines whether your modal will fill the entire view. Setting this to true will render the modal over a transparent background.

> TYPE : bool, REQUIRED : No

```js
<Modal visible={props.visible} transparent={true} animationType='slide' >
```

Comment: @David If my answer was helpful, would you choose the 'V' sign and arrow?

Comment: Damn what a dumb mistake on my part, for those who are not sure of what @hong developer is saying. It means to use `boolean` values of `true` or `false`. My mistake was that i put `"true"` which works for IOS but not for Android. Instead it should have been `{true}` or `{false}`